# c code to convert decimal value to its devanagari character

Tags: c

I have written a c code that reads binary data from a text file and maps it to its decimal using a predefined array.

```
int table[row][col]={
                      {2309,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                      {2310,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
                      {97,0,0,0,0,0,1,1},
                      {................}
                    };
```

Where 2309,2310,97 etc represents decimal value(ascii) of devanagari and english characters.
Now I want to convert this decimal value to its corresponding character and write it to a text file. This is easy to do for english characters. But i really don't have any idea to do this for hindi characters. I searched a lot but nothing worked for me. I want to do it in c only. Any help will be very useful.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hindi characters are gonna be unicode, not ASCII.

Comment: Have you tried printing the characters as *wide* characters? E.g. using `"%lc"` when using [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), or using [`wprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf) instead?

Comment: yes sir I tried wprintf too, but it is not printing any thing. :(

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, Hindi chars require [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). For example, with Visual Studio you would:

```
wchar_t str[] = {2309, 2310, 97, 0};
wprintf(L"%s\r\n", str);
```

If you have the right font, this prints: अआa

Comment: i tried using it in visual studio, but it is printing ? there. I am getting these values as integer. I converted it into string using atoa(), when i am trying to use it like wchar_t, it is giving incompatible type error. I am getting single integer value at a time. Right now i am working on gcc.

Comment: it is printing some unknown symbol on terminal.